# Different approaches of writing css

Tags: css

In general, CSS can be written in 3 ways

**Inline CSS**

```
<div style="float:left; border: 1px solid #000;">Hello</div>
```

**Internal CSS in the head section of HTML**

```
<style>
.div_class
{
    float:left; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>

<div class="div_class">Hello</div>
```

And lastly

**External CSS in another external CSS file**

```
<head>
<link href="//abc.com/css/style.css"/>
</head>

<div class="div_class">Hello</div>
```

So my question is, can anybody explain me the pros and cons of these three methods and situation when I should be using them.

Comment: inline css and internal css increase the size of the html, and only work on current page, which is a mess when you had more than one page, external css is the best, it not adding the size of the html, plus you can reuse in any page just by include the css

Comment: Having the same CSS on each page means it has to be downloaded anew for each page, rather than cached.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Inline CSS:

#### Pros:

- Server does not need to load more than one item.

#### Cons:

- Readability is poor.
- Only good if that element is the only one with the same attributes on the site.
- Hard to edit on large scale.
- Can't declare media queries.
- Can't declare `::pseudo` selectors
- Can't reuse the CSS on other pages

### Internal CSS in the Head Section of Html:

#### Pros:

- Server does not need to load more than one item.
- Readability is a little better.
- Can declare media queries.

#### Cons:

- Server/browser is unable to cache the file, making the load on a larger site larger.
- If site has more than one page, harder to edit. (if the header is not shared)
- Can't reuse the CSS on other pages.
- Hard to edit on large scale.

### External CSS in Another File:

#### Pros:

- Readability is the best.
- Easy to edit on large scale.
- Can be cached on a server.
- Can declare media queries.

#### Cons:

- Server must make more than one request.

### Summary:

Because most servers are not affected with an extra request and most browsers can do parallel requests (load time is not affected), most website developers use external css in another file for the ease of editing & the fact that they only need to edit the css once to read a whole site (if the header is not shared).

Answer (score 0):

For external css vs. internal css in the header, there is no difference
in how the browser renders the styling.

However, an external file will allow you to re-use the styles across several pages, 
at the cost of an extra http request from the client (which, with caching is cheap anyways)
It also would allow you to change styles on the entire site quickly, simply by replacing that file or files, whereas the other two methods would require editing each page/element with the old styling to the new styling. For obvious reasons, external files should be preferred.

The internal css could possibly be appropriate if the style will not be reused any other page, to save a request. However, it's quite possible that as your site expands, you will want to use those styles somewhere else, and since there's no difference you might want to consider using an external file instead of internal css.

Inline css will over-ride other css styling. So, not only does it make the html code harder to read, plus all the disadvantages of internal css, but on top of that it will also prevent the application of less-specific styles, which could be an issue for site maintainability. In general, I try to only use it in two occasions: debugging, and in combination with javascript. (though even with javascript it is 'cleaner' to add and remove classes).